# ¿Cual es la diferencia funciones y métodos en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Como dice el titulo de la pregunta, quisiera saber cual es la diferencia entre un método y una función en cuanto al trabajo con Objetos o Arrays Asociativos en Javascript.

Estuve leyendo un libro de javascript y dice que:

> **Una función** es aquel fragmento de código que al llamarse esta ejecuta una acción, una función al trabajarse con un objeto puede ejecutar una acción sobre este , es decir funcionar como un método pero no ser un método en si.
>
> Por otro lado **los métodos** decía que eran un conjunto de
> funcionalidades, o funciones que dependen del objeto.

esto fue lo que entendí pero no me queda claro por completo su diferencia.

**Quisiera saber cual es su diferencia y si es posible un ejemplo de ello**

Comment: Básicamente, los métodos son "funciones que pertenecen a una clase". Para llamar a un método utilizas un objeto, en plan "objecto.metodo(arg1, arg2);", mientras que para llamar a una función no necesitas ningún objeto: "funcion(arg1, arg2);

Comment: @Potray porque no agregas mas contenido y publicas tu respuesta?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Respuesta simple: **ninguna**.

En Javascript, la seleccion entre llamar a un *método* (función *dentro* de un objeto) o una función, se realiza **en el momento de la llamada**:

```
MiObjeto.function( args )
```

es **lo mismo** que si haces

```
function( args )
```

La **unica** diferencia es el valor de la variable *interna* `this`. Dicha variable:

- En el primer ejemplo indicado, *apuntaría* al objeto `MiObject`.
- En el segundo ejemplo, el valor de dicha variable depende de si estamos o no en el *modo estricto*.

Si estamos en *modo estricto*, `this` sería `undefined`.

Si **no** estamos en *modo estricto*, `this` seria:

1. En el navegador, el objeto `window`.
2. En Nodejs, el objeto `global`.

Podemos verlo como si, en **cualquier llamada a cualquier función**, **siempre** se nos pasará un primer argumento *oculto*:

```
miFunction( this, arg1, arg2, ... ) { ... }
```

Ese `this` es el que elegimos **al hacer la llamada**.

```
MiObjeto.miFunction( arg1, arg2 )
```

Estamos indicando **explicitamente** el `this` a usar: `MiObjeto`.

```
miFunction( arg1, arg2 )
```

`this` **implícito**: `window` o `undefined`.

Answer (score 4):

La diferencia entre un método y las funciones es que, un método es una función asociada o "ligada" a un objeto y mientras una función es un simple bloque de código independiente que puede ser llamado en un programa.